# Green button while active "save data"

Tags: javascript

How to make this button "save data" green or red while it's triggered/activated?

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
if (event.keyCode == 13){
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

var searchText = "Save data";
var found;

for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
  if (aTags[i].textContent == searchText) {
    found = aTags[i];
    break;
  }
}


if (found) {
found.click ();
}
else {
console.log('err');
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to it with your colour/styles and whatnot. E.g.:

```
element.classList.add("make-it-green");
```

Also, it would be helpful if you provided a bit more context.